# why getting The view firstapp.views.perticular_customers didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have created a view, able to retrieve, update and delete perticular object from data base and when ever i am trying the url `path('perticularcustomer/<int:var>', perticular_customers, name='perticular_customers')` i get :-

```
The view firstapp.views.perticular_customers didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

**views.py:-**

```
@csrf_exempt
def perticular_customers(request, var):

    try:
        customer = Customers.objects.get(id=var)
    except Customers.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request == 'GET':
        serialize = CustomersSerializer(customer)
        return JsonResponse(serialize.data, safe=False)

    elif request == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serialized = CustomersSerializer(customer, data=data)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return JsonResponse(serialized.data)
        return JsonResponse(serialized.errors, status=400)

    elif request == 'DELETE':
        customer.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `request.method`:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
```